# Skipping the errors and recording downloads in kdb

Tags: kdb

I am trying to use kdb q script to download file from remote source.
How can I make the download keep going if there is an error?
also, how can i mark it down what its downloaded in linux when there are other files in the same directory???

Here is my code:

```
file:("abc.csv";"def.csv");
dbdir:"/home/terry/";
dlFunc:{
  system "download.sh abc.com user /"get /remote/path/",x /",dbdir};
dlFunc each file;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking how to continue downloading other files if one file fails then you can put a protected eval around your `dlFunc each file`, e.g.

```
@[dlFunc;;()]each file;
```

You could capture the list of failed files using something like:

```
badfiles:();
{@[dlFunc;x;{y;badfiles,:enlist x}x]}each file;
```

Then inspect the `badfiles` list afterwards. The ones that succeeded would be:

```
file except badfiles
```

Comment: thanks!! do you know how to track what its downloaded to the disk?

Comment: this is covered by the last part in Terry's answer. `file except badfiles` will be a list of all files which successfully downloaded as they aren't in `badfiles`